# Previously written code, developer made a static var that returns a block?

Tags: swift

I was looking at some old code, and found this

```
enum Environment: String {
    static var current: Environment = {
        return .Develop
    }()
```

I'm wondering why write it this way, instead of:

```
enum Environment: String {
    static var current: Environment = .Develop
```

Are they functionally the same?  Is the fact that it's a var within an `enum` that makes a difference?

I believe I'm looking at a block that doesn't have it's parameter or return type defined, so the compiler is smart and determines that the return type is an `Environment`, and is therefore fine with setting this block as the initial value of this var

Does anybody have additional insight?  I would like to update it to the second method, because I believe it just makes more sense looking at it

Comment: This is more like `lazy` initialization where you may need reference to `self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "block" isn't "returned". The *closure* is defined, and executed *immediately*, returning `.Develop`, which is saved to `current`.

This is useful when you need something to occur during initialization of the variable, but in this, `static var current: Environment = .Develop` is sufficient, and preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the correction with the terminology.  I'm still relatively new from Objective-C 

Makes sense, the () is executing it immediately because it's outside of a declaration